# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jqgrid when using setSelection after an addrowdata

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
$(grid).jqGrid('addRowData', window.lastsel2, datarow);     

      setTimeout(function () {
            $(grid).jqGrid('setSelection', window.lastsel2);
        }, 1800);
```

If set a timer like above the error occur only sometime. if i set without timer it happens always. 
is there anyway to know when the addrowdata ends in order to set the selection without having the error and without using a timer?

Comment: It could be important to know **which version of jqGrid you use?** It's not clear what you want to do. Why you use **global** `lastsel2`? Do you use `onSelectRow` in the grid? Do you want that `onSelectRow` will be called by `setSelection`? the code of `setSelection` don't use `length` property of any object. In which internal function the error take place? Do you try to use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`? In which line you have the error?

Comment: thnx for the prompt response. Last jqgrid version i think 445. Yes i use onselect row: the intention is after the grid initialize I want to add a first empty row and right after this put the selection and the focus in a specific cell. Onselectrow I have the editrow and the focus of the cell. So i need only to setselection but this method give me that error when executed right after addrow.I didnt try to put src. anyway the exception is handled because its showed in an a small pop window. this error occur even when I am fast clicking on a cell with the mouse right after grid init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after debugging with jqgrid.js rather than the min version I found the problem was on the custom creation of a cell. So problem was on my code jqgrid works fine.